# android Locale.Builder() doesn't mirror the page in right-to-left locales

Tags: android, locale, right-to-left

When I use

```
locale = new Locale("ar");
```

the screen is mirrored in the right way.

In order to give the option to set the numeric system, i have to use the Locale.Builder() inserted with lollipop.

```
locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ar").setRegion("MA").setExtension(Locale.UNICODE_LOCALE_EXTENSION, "nu-latn").build();
```

The problem is that in this way the screen is not mirrored properly.
There is a way, like an Extension, to set the rtl attribute?

Comment: My impression is that the problem is with android ignoring RTL when you set the extension and not with Locale.Builder not doing its job. But I didn't find a way to fix it

Comment: BTW: is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: I've create an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION: 
In order to mirror the screen properly, you have to use the Configuration.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
config.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("ar"));
```

Comment: with this config you create a new Resources and then you use these resources for getting the strings?

Comment: How do you force the context to use this new config? context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

Comment: Another problem with the solution above is that after setting the extension the country is ignored so if you have en_gb and en_ie, en_gb is used for Ireland too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266789/arabic-number-in-arabic-text-in-android